# Associating Worksheets with their Names using OpenXML SDK 1.0

Tags: .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm using version 1.0 of Microsoft's OpenXML SDK to do some basic parsing of .xlsx files.  I can get and parse the worksheets, and I can get a list of worksheet names, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to link up what name goes with what worksheet.

I understand that an element like `<sheet name="My Sheet" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1"/>` in the workbook is linked up to a specific worksheet via the relationships defined in `xl/_rels.xml`, but I can't see where any of the relationship info is exposed in the API.

I'm using C#, but any VB.NET examples would be just as helpful.

I feel like this should be dead simple, but I can't figure it out.  It also looks like it may be more straightforward in v2.0 of the SDK, but upgrading isn't an option at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh... yes, it ended up being dead simple.  The `WorkbookPart` class exposes a `WorksheetParts` property that I was hung up on using, but it also exposes a `GetPartById(relationshipId)` method.

Given a list of `<sheet/>` elements from the workbook XML - each of which contains both a name and a relationship id - I just needed to retrieve each WorksheetPart by id.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Iterate Sheets; Get Name and xref WorksheetPart (container for Worksheet)
foreach (Sheet sheet in doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets)
{
    string sName = sheet.Name;
    string sID = sheet.Id;

    WorksheetPart part = (WorksheetPart)doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sID);
    Worksheet actualSheet = part.Worksheet;
}
```